# Linkedlist implementation

Tags: c, linked-list

I was trying this program which asks us to change a word in various ways .

For example if "MISSISSIPPI" is given to us
then output should be

MISP (Order of occurrence without repetition)

ISPM (Frequency)

IMPS (Alphabetical order)

I was able to do the alphabetical order thing , and could also code for the order of occurrence .I was able to run the alphabetical function successfully, but the code sort of hangs when it encounters order function , on CODEBLOCKS .

```
void ord()
{
    current = head1 ;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
      current1 = current -> next ;
      while(current1 != NULL)
      {
        if(current1 -> data == current -> data)
        {
           free(current1);
           current1 = current1 -> next ;
        }
        else
        current1 = current1 -> next ;
      }
      current = current -> next ;
    }
   ptr = head1 ;
   while(ptr != NULL)
   {
       printf("%c" , ptr->data) ;
       ptr = ptr -> next ;
   }
}
```

In this function current points to the head of the list , while current one points to the next of head . I increment current one and free the node which has a repeating alphabet . 
My query is why the code must be stopping ? Also suggest some logic for the frequency thing .

Thanks in advance

Comment: ordering isnt really related to the LL.  Thats just conditional information to push onto an associated LL, a node of assigned data.  Frequency... is a count of the number of items.  Not sure if your output needs to be LL, and you can use intermediate structures for procesing etc.. ex:  a max heap would easily build the order, and then you can just pop off the heap and push into the linked list for returning.

Comment: Run it with the debugger. BTW you dereference `current1` after you freed it. This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks , it says Segmentation fault in the 8th line of the function .

Comment: `free(current1); current1 = current1->next;` This is doomed. You can't access `current1`'s contents after freeing it.

Comment: Why would you ever use a linked list for this? Another artificial school assignment that will never apply to real world programming? The teacher should be teaching _when_ to use a linked list and _why_... or maybe they need to be taught that themselves...

Comment: Almost all the work is to be done by students these days . Teachers are dummies it seems .

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem lies in here.

```
if(current1 -> data == current -> data)
    {
       free(current1);
       current1 = current1 -> next ;
    }
```

Here you are freeing current1 and then advancing it.

My suggestion is you should use a temporary pointer to hold "current1"'s location and then advance it or what ever is needed.

Answer (score 1):

MISP (Order of occurrence without repetition)

Error is:

```
if(current1 -> data == current -> data)
{
    free(current1); // use a temporary varaible and move to next node and free
    current1 = current1 -> next ;
}
```

ISPM (Frequency): Quick idea.

Take an array of 26 size (as alphabets are 26. eg: `count[26]`)

- Increment the corresponding alphabet element by traversing through the linked list.
- at the end of the traverse you will be having the number of occurrences in the array.

say for element A -> increment A[0] ++;